# System specific variables in ansible

Tags: ansible

Ansible expects python 2. On my system (Arch Linux), "python" is Python 3, so I have to pass `-e "ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/bin/python2"` with every command.

```
ansible-playbook my-playbook.yml -e "ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/bin/python2"
```

Is there a away to set `ansible_python_interpreter` globally on my system, so I don't have to pass it to every command? I don't want to add it to my playbooks, as not all systems that runs the playbook has a setup similar to mine.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Well you can set in three ways

1. http://docs.ansible.com/intro_inventory.html#list-of-behavioral-inventory-parameters `ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/bin/python2` this will set it per host
2. Set it *host_vars/* `ansible_python_interpreter: "/usr/bin/python2"` this will set it per host
3. set it for **all nodes** in the file `group_vars/all` (you may need to create the directory `group_vars` and the file `all`) as `ansible_python_interpreter: "/usr/bin/python2"`

Hope that helps

Comment: I don't want it anywhere in the playbook, that's the point :) The fact that I need ansible python2 on my machine specifically shouldn't affect others using the playbook.

Comment: First the above only changes the inventory hosts_vars and groups_vars nothing in the playbook. But Are you managing Arch linux or mixed env?

Comment: This is not really the answer. I'm also looking for a solution not involving playbooks for I use Ansible Tower and when using a GIT project it uses Ansible's  python 2.6 with crypto errors where as my Ansible Tower has the 2.7 lib!

Comment: This does not involve playbooks. this is defined in on of the following a) inventory file b) host_vars or c) group_vars. your not changing the playbook or any role at this level so 100% portable. I would recommend group_vars

Answer (score 6):

I opted to use Ansible's ability to source inventory from a directory. In this manner I could define the `ansible_python_interpreter` for localhost only for the local machine

`inventory_dir/local`

```
[local]
localhost ansible_python_interpreter="/path/to/alternate/bin/python"
```

And then just use the directory as you would an inventory file.

`ansible-playbook -i inventory_dir playbook.yml`

Comment: you could just have called it `inventory` (you didn't call `local` `local_file`) :D

Answer (score 6):

For who want use local activated virtualenv python interpreter

in `inventory` file set

```
[local]
localhost ansible_python_interpreter=python
```